# java client for hazelcast cluster not working with listener

Tags: client, hazelcast

1.we have requirement to configure hazelcast client which listener to map events
like entry added , entry updated

2.please post link of examples.

3.we have embedded hazelcast . we want to it to make to client server model.

```
  client is able to connect to server :
  INFO: hz.client_0 [simpleserver] [3.10.1] HazelcastClient 3.10.1 
  (20180521 - 66f881d) is CLIENT_CONNECTED

   code in client to add listener:

 HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cg);
    
    hz.getMap("READ_ONLY_MAP").addEntryListener(new EntryAdapter<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
            System.out.println("entry added:" + event.getValue());
        }
    }, true);
```

hazelcast.xml :

```
<map name="READ_ONLY_MAP">
   <max-size policy="FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE">30</max-size>
   <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
 </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.able to find solution by implementing entry listener in both server and client on map.