# How can Hazelcast client be notified of an map updation in cluster

Tags: hazelcast

1.currently we have hazelcast embedded in war file.

2.we need to implement hazelcast server client where client needs to listen to values updated in map.

3.for example if one client updates map READ_ONLY_MAP then all other clients should get notified of it .

Comment: You should probably discuss these issues on https://slack.hazelcast.com/ instead of creating several issues here. This seems as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078997/java-client-for-hazelcast-cluster-not-working-with-listener

Answer (score 1):

1.able to solve this issue by adding entryLister on map on both server and client.